# Why is pandas DataFrame.to_csv float_format option using the old-style formatting?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, floating-point, formatting

I wanted to write a pandas DataFrame into a CSV. I wanted all floats to have 2 decimal points. So I used the [new formatting style of Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings):

```
indf.to_csv("myfile.csv", float_format="{:.2}")
```

But no, apparently `to_csv` wants the [old formatting style](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting)

```
indf.to_csv("myfile.csv", float_format="%.2f")
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is under discussion at the moment.  Have a look at https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/9448